# How to catch hyperlink clicks in UWP RichEditBox?

Tags: uwp, richeditbox, xaml-islands

I'm trying to use RichEditBox in a UWP custom component, which would be added to a WPF application through XamlIslands:

`<RichEditBox x:Name="editor" PointerPressed="editor_PointerPressed" Tapped="editor_Tapped" PointerReleased="editor_PointerPressed">`

I add hyperlinks with the following way:

`editor.Document.Selection.Link = "\"[the link]\"";`

It works fine and it opens the link in the browser when Ctrl+Click on it, but how can I catch that click event?

None of the callbacks are fire which I defined as a parameter in RichEditBox, so no PointerPressed, no PointerReleased, and no Tapped events are fired at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
   public class CustomRichTextBox: RichEditBox
{
    protected override void OnTapped(TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTapped(e);

        var tappedPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        var textRange = Document.GetRangeFromPoint(tappedPoint, PointOptions.ClientCoordinates);
        textRange.StartOf(TextRangeUnit.Link, true);

        var mylink = textRange.Link;
    }
}
```